# Как убрать "/" в конце ссылки?

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите разобраться с редиректами. Сейчас, если вбить адрес:
**адрес_сайта/sitemap.xml** то получаю 301 редирект на **адрес_сайта/sitemap.xml/**.

**htaccess:**

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  #php_flag default_charset UTF-8
  #php_value display_errors 1


<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  #php_flag default_charset UTF-8
  #php_value display_errors 1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /sitemap.*?\.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/tools/sitemap.wrapper.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /sitemap.*?\.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/tools/sitemap.wrapper.php [L]
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Как поставить исключения для **адрес_сайта/sitemap.xml**?